# Zend Framework 2 - bjyauthorize - Link new user with role

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I'm using `bjyauthorize` and I works great for existing users. I now are in need to add users dynamically.

I can set the connection between `User` and `Role` manually in the table `UserRoleLinker` but how do I it the way it is meant to be for new users? Maybe I missed something trivial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ZfcUser` `User` service triggers a `register.post` event after the user is inserted in the db, so you just need to listen to that event. You can do that by attaching a listener to the shared events manager in your module bootstrap.

The event instance received by your listener contains the user service itself, plus the `user` data, and the `form` that was used during registration, which should be enough to make the link

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $events = $app->getEventManager();
    $shared = $events->getSharedManager();
    $sm = $app->getServiceManager();

    $shared->attach('ZfcUser\Service\User', 'register.post', function ($e) use ($sm) {
         $userService = $e->getTarget();
         $newUser = $e->getParam('user');
         $registrationForm = $e->getParam('form');
         // do something with the new user info, eg, assign new user role...
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! do you have an example as well for the linking itself?

Comment: Afraid not Ron, I haven't used bjyauth/zfcuser for a while, and I never got as far as linking roles when I was tinkering with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full solution:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    //You need a copy of the service manager and it has to be set as a member for the lambda function to call it
    $this->sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $zfcServiceEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager();

    $zfcServiceEvents->attach('register.post', function($e) {

        /** @var \User\Entity\UserPdo $user */
        $user = $e->getParam('user');

        //This is the adapter that both bjyAuthorize and zfcuser use
        $adapter     = $this->sm->get('zfcuser_zend_db_adapter');

        //Build the insert statement
        $sql = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql($adapter);

        //bjyAuthorize uses a magic constant for the table name
        $insert = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Insert('user_role_linker');
        $insert->columns(array('user_id', 'role_id'));
        $insert->values(array('user_id' => $user->getId(), 'role_id' => 'user'), $insert::VALUES_MERGE);

        //Execute the insert statement
        $adapter->query($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert), $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```